# Display large icon in Vaadin 8

Tags: icons, vaadin, vaadin8

Some versions of Vaadin offered [FontAwesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome) built-in. Later Vaadin came with its own collection of icons.

How can I use either of those in Vaadin 8?

With the new emphasis on [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow) (Vaadin 10+) and re-implementing with [Web Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components), I have not been able to find any documentation on how to use either of those Vaadin 8 compatible font sources.

How can I conveniently get some large icons displayed as widgets within my Vaadin 8 layout?

Answer (score 7):

There is some 8.x documentation regarding [font icons](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-fonticon.html) and [`VaadinIcons`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.3.1/com/vaadin/icons/VaadinIcons.html), as well as [creating your own font icons](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/UsingFontIcons.html).

Using them is as simple as `new Button("Add", VaadinIcons.PLUS);`, but you mentioned something about *some large icons* which you don't get out of the box AFAIK.

However, based on the above doc, the quick and dirty solution is using a label and some styles:

**Theme:**

```css
.big-icon .v-icon{
   font-size: 300px;
 }
```

**Code:**

```java
public class Icon extends VerticalLayout {
    public Icon() {
        Label image = new Label();
        image.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
        image.setValue(VaadinIcons.EYE.getHtml());
        image.addStyleName("big-icon");
        addComponent(image);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: quick and dirty icon]

---

Obviously you can proceed with the *madness*, and create a slightly more flexible label of your own that does not require modifying the styles, and can be updated at runtim. Something along the lines of:

```java
public class Icon extends Label {
    private static final String CONTENT = "<span class=\"v-icon v-icon-%s\" style=\"font-family: %s; color: %s; font-size: %spx;\">&#x%s;</span>";
    private Color color;
    private int size;
    private VaadinIcons icon;

    public Icon(VaadinIcons icon) {
        this(icon, Color.BLACK, 16);
    }

    public Icon(VaadinIcons icon, Color color, int size) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
        updateIcon();
    }

    public void setIcon(VaadinIcons icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
        updateIcon();
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        updateIcon();
    }

    private void updateIcon() {
        setValue(String.format(CONTENT,
                icon.name(),
                icon.getFontFamily(),
                color.name(),
                size,
                Integer.toHexString(icon.getCodepoint())));
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public enum Color {
        BLACK, GREEN
    }
}
```

Where `myLayout.addComponents(new Icon(VaadinIcons.PLUS), new Icon(VaadinIcons.INFO, Icon.Color.GREEN, 200));` results in:

[image: different icon colors and sizes]

---

There could be more elegant solutions, but this is as far as I went brainstorming because I didn't have such a need so far. I always used regular sized icons with buttons and labels. Anyhow, hopefully this should get you started.

Comment: Why is your `Icon` class a subclass of `VerticalLayout` with a `Label` inside, rather than just subclass `Label` directly?

Comment: @BasilBourque no particular reason, it's a default "pattern" I use for most of these kind of samples, where usually there are more components involved. Initially I just wanted a quick test, then I thought about going further by creating the custom label implementation so I started to experiment. Later I reverted the changes when writing the answer, but I guess I did not undo the initial rename (`LayouWithIcons` -> `Icon`). Feel free to update it to whatever you feel is appropriate. Cheers